# Mixin layers & static binding

Tags: c++, layer, mixins

I'm currently playing with mixin layers designs, and I'm stuck with an 
annoying problem. 
Let's consider the following basic mixin layer:

```
template <typename Next> 
struct Layer1 : public Next 
{ 
 struct A : public Next::A 
 { 
   void f() { g(); } 
   void g() {} 
 }; 
};
```

Nothing fancy here, just a simple mixin with 2 methods `f()` and `g()`. 
Notice that the `g()` call from `f()` is is statically binded to this 
specific `Layer1::A::g()`. 
Now, what I want is to be able to completely hook the methods of this 
mixin to implement, say, a logging layer:

```
template <typename Next> 
struct Layer2 : public Next 
{ 
 struct A : public Next::A 
 { 
   void f() 
   { 
     std::cout << "Layer2::A::f() [enter]" << std::endl; 
     Next::A::f(); 
     std::cout << "Layer2::A::f() [leave]" << std::endl; 
   } 
   void g() 
   { 
     std::cout << "Layer2::A::g() [enter]" << std::endl; 
     Next::A::g(); 
     std::cout << "Layer2::A::g() [leave]" << std::endl; 
   } 
 }; 
};
```

Considering `Layer2<Layer1<...>>`, the problem here is that any call of 
`f()` and `g()` from a layer above `Layer2` will properly cascade down to 
the `Layer2::A::g()`, and thus display the proper logging messages. But 
any call of `f()` and `g()` from below `Layer2` will not log anything since 
the call would have been statically binded to the `g()` available at the 
time the call was made. 
This means that calling `f()` from any layer above `Layer2` will obviously 
still always call `Layer1::A::g()` from `Layer1::A::f()` and not display 
the logging messages. 
I came up with 2 solutions to this problem:

1. Virtuality: clearly not acceptable. The whole point of mixin layers 
   is to avoid virtuality when not necessary.
2. Adding a template parameter to the layers to provide the previous 
   layer, something of the kind.

.

```
template <typename Next, template <typename> class Prev> 
struct Layer2 : public Next 
{ 
 typedef Next next_t; 
 struct A : public Next::A 
 { 
   void f() 
   { 
     std::cout << "Layer2::A::f() [enter]" << std::endl; 
     Next::A::f(); 
     std::cout << "Layer2::A::f() [leave]" << std::endl; 
   } 
   void g() 
   { 
     std::cout << "Layer2::A::g() [enter]" << std::endl; 
     Next::A::g(); 
     std::cout << "Layer2::A::g() [leave]" << std::endl; 
   } 
 }; 
}; 

template <typename Next, template <typename> class Prev> 
struct Layer1 : public Next 
{ 
 typedef Next next_t; 
 struct A : public Next::A 
 { 
   void f() 
   { 
     std::cout << "Layer1::A::f() [enter]" << std::endl; 
     ((typename Prev<Layer1<Next,Prev> >::A*)this)->g(); 
     std::cout << "Layer1::A::f() [leave]" << std::endl; 
   } 
   void g() 
   { 
     std::cout << "Layer1::A::g() [enter]" << std::endl; 
     std::cout << "Layer1::A::g() [leave]" << std::endl; 
   } 
 }; 
}; 

typedef Layer2<Layer1<Layer0,Layer2>,NullType> Application;
```

Well, it works, but I would like to hide this second template 
parameter since it is redundant. 
I wondered if any of you ever encountered such problem, and what 
solutions did you developped to solve it, since there is a clear lack 
of articles on mixin layers.

Comment: This is a typical use of CRTP. You want static binding to the outermost template and I see no way to pass it implicitly. It does have an impact on reusability: If I want to add a third layer, I cannot inherit from your layer, because I have to change the outermost layer.

Comment: For those who don't know what is all about "mixin layer". You should edit your question in black box format. i.e what is your input and what is the desired output. That will truly help making it clear that what you actually want.